# How to access I18n Bean from inside a task

Tags: bamboo

I am trying to create a plugin with a task, but I have trouble getting access to an instance of I18bean for retrieving internationalized message. Does anyone has a hint on how to do it ?

Comment: By the way, I tried to create the tag bamboo-plugin-development, But I don't have enough reputation. Can somebody with enough clout could do it ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You need to add a constructor with a `I18nBeanFactory` parameter and use this one for retrieving an `I18nBean`

```
public class CreateFileTask implements TaskType {

    public I18nBeanFactory i18nBeanFactory;

    public CreateFileTask(I18nBeanFactory i18nBeanFactory) {
        this.i18nBeanFactory=i18nBeanFactory;
    }
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public TaskResult execute(TaskContext taskContext) throws TaskException {
        I18nBean i18nBean = i18nBeanFactory.getI18nBean();
        i18Bean.getText(...);
    }
}
```